# Better to use strtotime or DateInterval to increment the date

Tags: php, date, increment

I got a PHP script that gets the information for each day and puts it in a database so I need to increment  or decrement the date. I want to know if I should use strtotime or DateInterval to increment the date or does it matter? For example:

```
$date = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime("2017-1-31"));
$date = strtotime("+1 day", $date);
```

or

```
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$date = new DateTime('2017-01-30');
```

Comment: My preference would be to use the DateInterval, it's much cleaner and nicer to work with. By using a DateTime object you don't need to keep converting from a string to an integer and then ultimately back to a string.

Comment: `$date = new DateTime(); $date->modify("-1 day");` - that looks much cleaner to me. Given the fact you can easily drop in time zone information, I don't really see the reason to use `strtotime` or other procedural solutions to modify the date. Now, if you personally think you can understand `strtotime` or `date` functions in an easier way, then go for it. Just keep it consistent and clean so you can always return to your code without any questions.

Comment: Consider the `strtotime()` method to be the "old" way and no longer the "proper" way.  You can use it but there is a more "proper" better ways to do it.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. I'm going to try using the $date = new DateTime(); $date->modify("-1 day");